# Extending multiple mixins with Vue and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have following simple example

```
const mixin1 = Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    mixin1_prop():number {
      return 10;
    },
  },
});

const mixin2 = Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    mixin2_prop():number {
      return 20;
    },
  },
});

// Now in component I want to extend both mixin1 and mixin2

mixin1.extend(mixin2).extend({
  created() {
    console.log(this.mixin1_prop);
    console.log(this.mixin2_prop);
  },
});
```

TypeScript compailer is complaining for mixin2_prop with error `Property 'mixin2_prop' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Re`

even thought when the example is run on run time everything works as intended and both number 10 and number 20 are printed to console.

Does anybody know how to trick TS compiler so that he recognize both mixins inside of the component code?